# SOQL No such column on a non custom field (Event -> Type)

Tags: soql, salesforcedx

Executing this in the Developer console

```
SELECT Event.Subject,Event.ActivityDate, Event.EventSubtype, IsAllDayEvent, Event.Type      
FROM Event
```

returns the error

```
No such column 'Type' on entity 'Event'.
```

even though "Type" is defined as a field in this documentation.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_event.htm

I get this error with other fields such as ClientGuid. Type is also listed in setup as a field on the Event object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my little Developer Edition org, I wasn't able to see or query the standard `Type` field either. I could see that it is a standard field, and I could add it to my layouts, but it did not appear when I went to a task/event/call/what-have-you.

Looking at the FLS (field-level security) settings, this field was not marked as being visible (read-only implies visible, so that setting isn't really important for this discussion), not even for the system admin profile.

While enforcing FLS is often left to developers, FLS does affect what you can query and see on page layouts.

Changing the FLS so that, at the bare minimum, it is visible to your profile should resolve the issue.

I know I've forgotten to update FLS for a new *custom* field when doing a deployment, but I didn't think that would be an issue for *standard* fields...

Comment: Great! Changing the FLS did the trick.